Wrapping Table Headers in PDF using Python - fpdf
I'm building trying to build a pdf report in Python using fpdf. I want to take some data from my analysis stored in a DataFrame and create tables and graphs. Just like what you would do in Excel. My issues is I can't see to get the headers to wrap text like you would get if you used the "Wrap Text" function in Excel if you were creating a table. I've tried multiple iterations and the best I've come up with is the below:
data1 = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Values': [10.1234, 20.5678, 15.9101, 25.1121]
}

data2 = {
    'Category': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
    'I expect this to wrap': [30.2345, 40.6789, 35.3456, 45.7890]
}




df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Create a PDF class
class PDF(FPDF):
    def header(self):
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        self.cell(0, 10, 'PDF Report with Charts and Tables', 0, 1, 'C')
        self.ln(10)

    def chapter_title(self, title):
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
        self.cell(0, 10, title, 0, 1, 'L')
        self.ln(5)

    def table(self, df):
        self.set_font('Helvetica', '', 10)
        
        # Calculate column widths
        index_col_width = max(self.get_string_width(str(index)) for index in df.index) + 10
        col_widths = {col: self.get_string_width(col) + 10 for col in df.columns}
        max_col_width = max(col_widths.values())

        # Row height
        row_height = self.font_size + 5

        # Header
        self.set_fill_color(255, 255, 255)
        self.set_draw_color(0, 0, 0)
        
        # Wrap headers
        x_start = self.get_x()
        y_start = self.get_y()
        
        self.multi_cell(index_col_width, row_height, 'Member', border=1, align='C', fill=True)
        self.set_xy(x_start + index_col_width, y_start)
        
        for col_name in df.columns:
            x_start = self.get_x()
            y_start = self.get_y()
            self.multi_cell(max_col_width, row_height, col_name, border=1, align='C', fill=True)
            self.set_xy(x_start + max_col_width, y_start)

        self.ln(row_height)

        # Data
        fill = False
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            fill = not fill
            self.set_fill_color(240, 240, 240) if fill else self.set_fill_color(255, 255, 255)
            self.cell(index_col_width, row_height, str(index), border=1, fill=True, align='L')
            for cell in row:
                formatted_cell = f"{cell:.2f}" if isinstance(cell, float) else str(cell)
                self.cell(max_col_width, row_height, formatted_cell, border=1, fill=True, align='L')
            self.ln(row_height)

# Create a PDF document
pdf = PDF()
pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=True, margin=15)

# Add first table
pdf.add_page(orientation='L')
pdf.chapter_title('Table 1: Category vs Values')
pdf.table(df1)

# Add second table
pdf.add_page(orientation='L')
pdf.chapter_title('Table 2: Category vs Values')
pdf.table(df2)


# Create chart for demonstration
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5.63))  # Adjust figure size to fit within page
plt.bar(df1['Category'], df1['Values'], color='skyblue')
plt.title('Sample Bar Chart')
plt.xlabel('Category')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.savefig('bar_chart.png')  # Save the figure
plt.close()



# Add chart
pdf.add_page(orientation='L')
pdf.chapter_title('Sample Bar Chart')
pdf.image('bar_chart.png', x=10, y=30, w=250)  # Adjust the positioning and size as needed

# Output the PDF
pdf.output('report_test_2_check.pdf')

This gives me the below:

Below is an excel example of what I expect for the second table:


try to use FPDF2 :

pip install fpdf2

this version is the last one today and it solves the wrapping problem.
this is a code that explains that :
from fpdf import FPDF

TABLE_DATA = (
    ("wrap this text wrap this text", "wrap this text wrap this text", "wrap this text wrap this text", "wrap this text wrap this text"),
    ("Jules", "Smith", "34", "San Juan"),
    ("Mary", "Ramos", "45", "Orlando"),
    ("Carlson", "Banks", "19", "Los Angeles"),
    ("Lucas", "Cimon", "31", "Saint-Mathurin-sur-Loire"),
)

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Times", size=16)

with pdf.table() as table:
    for data_row in TABLE_DATA:
        row = table.row()
        for datum in data_row:
            row.cell(datum)


pdf.output('table.pdf')

the code above will give the result below:


Thanks Mohammed. I get an error when I run it though. I get " 'FPDF' object has no attribute 'table' " when I run your code.

@Farrep7 it is because of the version of the FPDF, I used in my code FPDF2, try to delete the previous one and install the FPDF2
